# Spring boot EmbeddedServletContainer - GenericJDBCException - Could not open connection

Tags: database, spring-boot, undertow

I'm developing an Spring Boot 1.3 based application with an EmbeddedServletContainer, managing its own DB connections. When the server is left unused for a long time (Probably over the weekend), as there could have been stale connections to the DB, I started to see the below exception trace.

```
Wrapped by: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Could not open connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) ~[undertow-servlet-1.2.11.Final.jar!/:1.2.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) ~[undertow-servlet-1.2.11.Final.jar!/:1.2.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:249) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.M5.jar!/:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) ~[undertow-servlet-1.2.11.Final.jar!/:1.2.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) ~[undertow-servlet-1.2.11.Final.jar!/:1.2.11.Final]
```

The only way I see to fix the error is to restart the server. Is there anyway that would help the server to open a new DB connection when there are such "no connection" exceptions?

Thanks!

Comment: Your connections might not be not getting closed and there are no more connections in the connection pool or reached limit at server side.

Comment: The server hasnt reached the limit. That I'm pretty sure. But, in the other scenario of no more connections in connection pool, doesnt it make sense to automatically create one?

Comment: When the connections defined in the pool has maxed out, the pool will not create more.

Comment: The same exception is thrown when the application is running my laptop and the machine (windows) sleeps for a while and I start re-using the application. (In which case the DB server could have potentially closed the open connections).

Answer (score 0):

I think the blog [here](http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2010/01/09/could-not-inspect-jdbc-autocommit-mode/) better explains the issue. I fixed it accordingly and the issue doesnt happen any more!

The Fix is as below, on datasource config, I added the below properties:

```
validation-query: "SELECT 1;"
test-on-borrow: true
```

Thanks Naresh Jain!